# How to set Stack trace depth of PHP's error log?

Tags: php, configuration, xdebug, ini

In my `php.ini` I set this line:

```
error_log = c:/php/php_errors.log
```

It enables output of errors into the specified file.

However, it always outputs maximum of 4, i.e.:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ServiceNotFoundException
Stack trace:
#0 PluginManager.php(124): AbstractPluginManager->get('getEntityManage...', NULL)
#1 AbstractController.php(301): PluginManager->get('getEntityManage...', NULL)
#2 AbstractController.php(316): AbstractController->plugin('getEntityManage...')
#3 AbstractPluginManager.php on line 133
^^^ stops at depth 4 always
```

I want to control the stack depth.  How?
I could not find anything on http://php.net/error-log

Comment: What happens if you set "log_errors_max_len" to 0 in php.ini?

Comment: That might also be runtime configurable:  ini_set("log_errors_max_len",0);

Comment: you are the man, it works!

Comment: Thanks, happy to help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value is "log_errors_max_len", in php.ini or possibly configurable via ini_set():

```
ini_set("log_errors_max_len",0);
```

Comment: thanks it finally saves me from having to go into 3rd party files to put my own `debug_print_backtrace`

Comment: Hopefully useful fact from PHP 8: `log_errors_max_len` has no effect as of PHP 8.0.0, and is removed as of PHP 8.1.0

Comment: log_errors_max_len Had no effect as of PHP 8.0.0, removed as of PHP 8.1.0.